# Как в Битрикс инициализировать бизнес-процесс при получении письма?

Tags: битрикс

В сервисах->почта->правила можно создать правило, по которому будет обрабатываться входящее письмо.

Но вот как инициализировать БП в этом условии, никак не могу разобраться.

Что-то в документации такого не нашел.

Помогите или ссылочкой или советом.

Comment: А что должно происходить после получения письма?

Comment: Бп просто на получение письма сделать нельзя. Можно сделать запуск процесса на создание лида, если из письма создается лид. Что у Вас происходит после получения письма? Может быть можно к чему-то привязаться. Так же важный момент - облачный битрикс или коробочный.